# Why isn't my PHP code running on the production server?

Tags: php

I have tested my php code on my test server and everything worked fine, now I upload it to my web hosting on godaddy.com and each page works except one.  The page simply outputs nothing, literally nothing

Out of frustration I put the following code on the production server

```
<BR>1
<? PHP
echo "<br>2";
?>
<BR>3
```

and this displays 1 & 3.
Every other page of php code works on godaddy and this page works 100% of the time on the test server.

EDIT
It seems to be comments are stopping it from working, when i delete the comments from the file it seems to work - but why? and how can I test this is actually the case?

---

It seems that the problem is the comments, wether I use the # or // to make comments it has stopped the code!

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../functions/common.php");
$sqldb = open_database();
include("../functions/create_game.php");
header('Location:'.$_SESSION['web_site'].'/home.php');  //Go back to the home page
?>
```

BUT, if I put comments on the end of any other line the code stops!
I know this sounds strange but I have been working on it for over a n hour and putting comments on and off to see if this is actually the problem.

Comment: Have you tried running `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` on the server?

Comment: Note that the space makes "<?" a short tag, which are disabled (for good reason) on GoDaddy hosts. As for the page outputting nothing, did you check the source view? Do you see your PHP code there? Hopefully, you aren't using [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br) in your production code.

Comment: Using an uppercase PHP open tag works with the PHP interpreter, but isn't standard practice and may not work well with some tools.

Comment: The question could use a few more [details](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) to make it complete and the problem reproducible. Please include a link to a live page. What file extension are you using for the pages?

Comment: Not normally to be used in production but it may help you in this case. Try putting this at the top of your file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. This will turn on reporting of all errors and warnings

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see a reply to @Jack Maney's comment, so I'll repeat it.

Create a single file in httproot called `info.php`

Put the following line in that file:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

View http://mysite.example.com/info.php (where mysite.example.com is your domain name). If you get nothing, then you'll need to get in touch with GoDaddy customer support, (480) 505-8877

Comment: Have done that now, changed the code to <?php phpinfo();echo "<BR>HI";?> and this shows all the php info but does not display the work HI

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the space before the 'php'

Comment: Sorry but that was my fault when writing out this question, this is my first question so I don't know how the space got it there :(

Answer (score -2):

is php in lowercase? `<?PHP` might not be recognized while `<?php` is standard

Comment: Have now put it all lower case but no difference :(  Other pages are in upper case and they work